# Stat test for unequal sampling time/measurement time intervals (retrospective, clinical data, blood test results)

Tags: unevenly-spaced-time-series

To compare two treatments (independent variables = intervention A vs intervention B), dependent variables are lipid levels (i.e. LDL, HDL, TC, TG) in scales. Blood samplings were collected at various time points for 3 times. What is the best test to calculate the mean change for each dependent variables while factoring in the different measurement time intervals?

Comment: Welome to Cross Validated! There are ways to do this type of thing, but to help us suggest the correct one please say more about the study design and what you mean specifically about the "mean change" here. How many of the measurements were made prior to the intervention and how many after? If you expect the lipid levels to change with time after intervention, then perhaps you want an estimate of "mean change" at some fixed time after intervention for all individuals? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.